# hyperref, babel and subequations conflict

Tags: hyperref, babel, incompatibility, subequations

I am trying to use `subequations` in a document. Playing around with my preamble I found out that if I use `babel` and `hyperref` package at the same time, a fatal error is occured and no `.pdf` is produced.

I know I can play around with the `equation counter`, to make an enumeration 1.1a, 1.1b, but I was wondering why is this happening with `subequations` and if there's a way to fix this.

My code is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{%
    %pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    %colorlinks,
    %citecolor=red,
    %filecolor=Darkgreen,
    %linkcolor=blue,
    %urlcolor=cyan!50!black!90
%}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        1+1=&2\\
        2+2=&4
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don’t get any errors with your code on MiKTeX 2.9. I’m assuming your system is up-to-date?

Comment: The posted code runs without error in TeXlive 2013

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I am running `MikTex 2.8`. Do you think that this might be the problem? Have you ever heard of something similar in `MikTeX 2.8`?

Comment: No, but MiKTeX 2.8 is not maintained anymore and probably some of the old packages you have cause the issue.

Comment: @karlkoeller: So the solution is to update to `MikTex 2.9`?

Comment: Definitely. It is always a bad practice to work with obsolete systems which can not be updated (IMHO!).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed in the current release(s) of the packages involved.
